# Как создать новый проект gulp если уже есть другой?

Tags: node.js, git, github, gulp

У меня есть учебный проект gulp, который я хочу сохранить для того, чтобы сверять с последующими проектами. Одновременно я хочу создать второй проект для работы над другим сайтом в github pages.

Вопрос в следующем:

- Нужно ли переустанавливать node.js и gulp, если уже есть действующий проект gulp?
- Если нет то как начать работу в новом проекте gulp?

Comment: Что-то я сначала подумал, что вы хотите получить копию текущего проекта, чтобы в ней продолжить работу над новым проектом. Сейчас перечитал и сомневаюсь, что правильно вас понял. Вы копию хотите или с нуля?

Comment: `надеюсь вопрос был понятен` – наполовину. Отформатировал, теперь вроде стало понятнее, но ещё не всё.

Comment: Меня интересует создание нового проэкта gulp, при том что есть уже действующий проэкт gulp, из существующего проэкта мне нужны только код файла gulpfile.js и package.json чтобы сразу работали все плагины. Извиняюсь если не сильно понятно объясняюс, я новичок в этом.

Comment: с github собираюсь использовать только второй gulp проэкт а первый, тот что уже есть не связан с git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Что происходит (ответы на вопросы)

> У меня есть проэкт gulp, учебный, который я хочу сохранить для того чтобы сверять с последующими проэктами.

Похоже, что исходные условия таковы:

- Есть проект, использующий node.js и gulp
- Этот проект лежит в локальном репозитории git
- Этот репозиторий связан с репозиторием на GitHub
- Сайт разворачивается на GitHub Pages

> Одновременно я хочу создать второй для работы над другим сайтом в github pages.

Для каждого сайта на GH Pages нужен отдельный репозиторий на GitHub. Других ограничений нет.

> Вопрос в следующем: нужно ли для этого переустанавливать node.js и нужно ли удалять gulp и устанавливать заново если уже есть действующий проэкт gulp?

Обычно, зависимости устанавливаются один раз. Вы же не переустанавливаете ОС ради каждой новой программы? Исключение — когда вы устанавливаете их в какое-то виртуальное окружение (в том числе vagrant, docker и т.п.). Тогда в каждое окружение нужно заново устанавливать нужные зависимости.

> Если нет то как начать работу в новом проэкте, какие должны быть команды в строке для начала нового проэкта gulp?

## Как копировать проект локально и на гитхабе

1. На рабочей машине копируйте куда-нибудь папку с вашим проектом. Важно копировать саму папку, а не все файлы из этой папки, потому что во втором случае скрытые файлы не копируются. В результате у вас получится полная копия проекта, вместе с копией локального репозитория git.
2. Откройте консоль в папке с копией проекта.

   Выполните команду:

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```

   Вы увидите адрес репозитория на гитхабе, который используется для первого проекта. Если вы используете авторизацию по логину и паролю (протокол HTTPS), адрес выглядит так:

   ```
   https://github.com/username/repo-name.git
   ```

   А если авторизуетесь по ключу (протокол SSH), то адрес выглядит так:

   ```
   git@github.com:username/repo-name.git
   ```
3. Создайте новый репозиторий на гитхабе.
4. Со страницы нового репозитория скопируйте адрес.
   Выбирайте аналогичный тому, который сейчас используете:

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. В консоли, в папке копии проекта, выполните следующую команду, чтобы переключить ваш локальный репозиторий на новый удалённый репозиторий на гитхабе:

   ```
   git remote set-url origin <адрес репозитория>
   ```

   Например:

   ```
   git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo-name.git
   ```
6. Запушьте содержимое нового проекта на гитхаб с помощью команды:

   ```
   git push origin -u master:master
   ```

Теперь у вас есть новый локальный репозиторий, он связан с новым репозиторием на гитхабе. Его содержимое вы запушили на гитхаб. Если GH Pages успешно работали раньше, то они продолжат работать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ценную информацию.